# Looping through csv file and take chuck of data according to condition

Tags: python, csv

I have an problem which i have not found any solution in all CSV posts i looked in.
I have csv of thousands of rows which the first column has a date and time stamp.
every 2 seconds there is new time stamp

note 1: **Very important note (which causes my problem) is that every date and time appears few times**

note 2: Dates are already sorted

my first 40 rows

```
30/07/2018 22:52:52,4,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:52,7,49,26

30/07/2018 22:52:52,6,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:52,5,51,26

30/07/2018 22:52:52,2,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:52,3,49,26

30/07/2018 22:52:55,4,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:55,7,49,26

30/07/2018 22:52:55,6,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:55,5,51,26

30/07/2018 22:52:55,2,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:55,3,49,26

30/07/2018 22:52:57,4,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:57,7,49,26

30/07/2018 22:52:57,6,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:57,5,51,26

30/07/2018 22:52:57,2,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:57,3,49,26

30/07/2018 22:52:59,4,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:59,7,49,26

30/07/2018 22:52:59,6,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:59,5,51,26

30/07/2018 22:52:59,2,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:59,3,49,26

30/07/2018 22:53:02,4,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:02,7,49,26

30/07/2018 22:53:02,6,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:02,5,51,26

30/07/2018 22:53:02,2,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:02,3,49,26

30/07/2018 22:53:04,4,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:04,7,49,26

30/07/2018 22:53:04,6,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:04,5,51,26

30/07/2018 22:53:04,2,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:04,3,49,26

30/07/2018 22:53:07,4,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:07,7,49,26

30/07/2018 22:53:07,6,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:07,5,51,26

30/07/2018 22:53:07,2,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:07,3,49,26

30/07/2018 22:53:09,4,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:09,7,49,26

30/07/2018 22:53:09,6,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:09,5,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:09,2,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:09,3,49,26
```

I need to take an input from user for example 5 and then take the last timestamp every 5 seconds and make dictionary out of columns 2 and 3.
so for input 5 ill have to take rows:

```
30/07/2018 22:52:59,4,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:59,7,49,26

30/07/2018 22:52:59,6,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:59,5,51,26

30/07/2018 22:52:59,2,50,26

30/07/2018 22:52:59,3,49,26

30/07/2018 22:53:09,7,49,26

30/07/2018 22:53:09,6,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:09,5,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:09,2,50,26

30/07/2018 22:53:09,3,49,26
```

the dictionary should look like this:

> {timestamp : {2nd column : 3rd columns}}
>
> {30/07/2018 22:52:59: {4:50,7:49,6:50,5:51,2:50,3:49}}

What i have until now works only 1 time for every time stamp meaning i get this dictionary for every timestamp:

> {30/07/2018 22:52:59: {4:50}, 30/07/2018 22:53:09:{4:50}}

This is my code:

```
with open(os.path.join(inputPath,filename),"r") as f:
            dictTemp = {}
            r = csv.reader(f)
            #Gets first date from node file
            minTime = dt.strptime(next(r)[0], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        #open file second time to loop through all rows
            for line in r:
                currentTime = dt.strptime(line[0], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
                if((currentTime-minTime).total_seconds() > 5):
                    minTime = currentTime
                    scenariotimeStamps.append((currentTime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")))
                    dictTemp[line[1]] = line[2]
                    dicComplete[str(currentTime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))] = dictTemp
```

Comment: It is kinda Unclear can you please keep it simple??

Comment: i tried to be as clear as i can and still give all the details

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
dictTemp[line[1]] = line[2]
dicComplete[str(currentTime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))] = dictTemp
```

You are overwriting the dict `dicComplete[str(currentTime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))]` in every iteration. Change the two lines to:

```
dictComplete.setdefault(str(currentTime.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")), {})[line[1]] = line[2]
```

And also, since you want to take all the rows of the same timestamp after verifying that it's at least 5 seconds since the last timestamp, instead of:

```
if((currentTime-minTime).total_seconds() > 5):
```

you should allow it if `currentTime` is equal to `minTime`:

```
if currentTime == minTime or (currentTime-minTime).total_seconds() > 5:
```

Comment: My problem is in the condition. i am check if the current timestamp is greater the 5 seconds. if it does i am setting the minimum time to current time and take 2nd and 3rd row into the dictionary. so the first time i am taking {4:50} and next time the condition is not fulfilled

Comment: Almost. it takes the first timestamp as well. this is what i get: {30/07/2018 22:52:52 : {2nd:3rd} , 30/07/2018 22:52:59 : {2nd:3rd}, 30/07/2018 22:53:07 : {2nd:3rd}}

Comment: It works for me. Can you show me your revised code by either editing my answer or editing your question?

Comment: Saw your revised code. Looks to be as I expected, but are you actually opening the file for a second time at where your commented `#open file second time to loop through all rows`? If not, that would explain the missing first timestamp.

Comment: I am not opening it again, its an comment i forgot to delete. and the problem is not timestamp missing its timestamp which i should not have in the dictionary but its there. the first time stamp "20180730225252" should not be in the dictionary